# Whole set of unit test cases pass but if I run individual it fails

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

Below is set of my unit test cases. I don't know if I have written it in a wrong way. but my all unit test cases pass if I run all at once( going in test explorer--> right click on CosmosDataTests--> Run) my all test cases passes. But If I try to run individual test case in the test explorer, it fails..saying "Owner resource not available." What wrong am I doing here??

here is my code:

```
public class CosmosDataFixture : IDisposable
    {
        public static readonly string CosmosEndpoint = "https://localhost:8081";
        public static readonly string EmulatorKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
        public static readonly string DatabaseId = "dummydatabase";
        public static readonly string RecordingCollection = "testcontainer";
        public static string Root = Directory.GetParent( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() ).Parent.Parent.FullName;
        public static DocumentClient client { get; set; }

        public async Task ReadAllData( DocumentClient client )
        {
            string path = Path.Combine( Root, @"TestData\Dummydata.json" );
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines( path );
            var jData = new List<JObject>();
            foreach( var line in lines )
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>( line );
                jData.Add( data );
            }
            Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( DatabaseId, RecordingCollection );
            foreach( var obj in jData )
            {
               await client.UpsertDocumentAsync( collectionUri, obj );
            }
        }

        public async Task ReadConfigAsync()
        {

          
            client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( CosmosEndpoint ), EmulatorKey,
                 new ConnectionPolicy
                 {
                     ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                     ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp

                 } );
            await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync( new Database { Id = DatabaseId } );
            await client.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ),
                new DocumentCollection { Id = RecordingCollection } );
            await ReadAllData( client );
        }    

        

        private async Task DeleteDatabaseFromPowerShell()
        {
           await client.DeleteDatabaseAsync( UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( DatabaseId ) );
        }
        public CosmosDataFixture()
        {
                      
            ReadConfigAsync();     
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
          DeleteDatabaseFromPowerShell();
        }
    }   
    public class CosmosDataTests : IClassFixture<CosmosDataFixture>
    {            

        [Fact]
        public async Task CheckDatabaseandCollectionCreation()
        {          
            List<string> collectionName = new List<string>();
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri( CosmosDataFixture.DatabaseId);
            var collections = await CosmosDataFixture.client.ReadDocumentCollectionFeedAsync( uri );
            foreach( var collection in collections )
            {
                collectionName.Add( collection.Id);
            }
            Assert.Contains( "testcontainer", collectionName );     
        }

        [Fact]
        public void AddDataInCosmosDbEmulator()
        { ...2nd test case..and so on}
```

Detailed Error message:

> Message:
> System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException : Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found. Learn more:
> https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"]}
> ActivityId: 1e276085-da33-42a0-8e45-9c5d0e951512, Request URI: /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/,
> RequestStats:
> RequestStartTime: 2021-07-05T12:17:54.9135143Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-07-05T12:17:54.9135143Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
> , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, Windows/10.0.19042 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.14.0
> ---- Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException : Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found. Learn more:
> https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found"]}
> ActivityId: 1e276085-da33-42a0-8e45-9c5d0e951512, Request URI: /apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/,
> RequestStats:
> RequestStartTime: 2021-07-05T12:17:54.9135143Z, RequestEndTime: 2021-07-05T12:17:54.9135143Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
> , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0, Windows/10.0.19042 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.14.0   Stack Trace:
> PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
> Pipeline.Invoke()
> CosmosDataTests.VerifyGetChangeFeedDocumentsForRecordings() line 177
> ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
> GatewayStoreClient.ParseResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings,
> DocumentServiceRequest request)
> GatewayStoreClient.InvokeAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, ResourceType resourceType, Uri physicalAddress, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)
> GatewayStoreModel.ProcessMessageAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> DocumentClient.ProcessRequestAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)
> DocumentClient.ProcessRequestAsync(String verb, DocumentServiceRequest request, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy
> retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String
> testAuthorization)
> ChangeFeedQuery`1.GetFeedResponseAsync(String resourceLink, ResourceType resourceType, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ChangeFeedQuery`1.ReadDocumentChangeFeedPrivateAsync[TResult](String
> link, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod,
> TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback) ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException) BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback)
> CosmosDBDocumentStore.GetChangeFeedDocuments[T](String& ContinuationToken, TimeSpan MaxAge, Int32 MaxResults) line 94
> projectName.GetChangeFeedDocuments[T](String& ContinuationToken, TimeSpan MaxAge, Int32 MaxResults) line 1037
> GetProjectNameChangedRecordingsCmd.ProcessRecord() line 74
> Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
> CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

Comment: i guess that means your 2nd, or 3rd... cases depend on the 1st one. and when you run all, it happens to run in order. but to prove, you have to debug and check the real exception.

Comment: no it does not, all are independent. and as far I know in xunit framework they dont run in an order

Comment: you're over confident. i say they **happen to** be in order. if they are independent, why do you get error? do you mean it is issue of xunit?

Comment: no its not an issue of xunit. it something wrong with my code design. If you see in constructor I am calling all stuffs required for my each unit test case, but it fails saying owner resource not available i.e. the db does not exists. which do not seems to be right.

Comment: can you paste the detailed error messages when run one by one?

Comment: i cant do await in the constructor

Comment: Could it be that `ReadConfigAsync` hasn't finished when you begin your tests?

Comment: you might be correct.. that is what I am asking if anything with design.. posted detailed error message

Comment: added one more question specific to error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256356/below-unit-test-sometime-pass-sometime-give-error-as-system-invalidoperationexc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured out, it was a async await issue. the method called in my constructor and in dispose was not awaited and thats why I was getting error. fixed it by adding .GetAwaiter().Getresult()

```
public CosmosDataFixture()
        {
                      
            ReadConfigAsync().GetAwaiter.GetResult();     
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
          DeleteDatabaseFromPowerShell().GetAwaiter.GetResult();
        }
```